# React-native-mapbox Draw Features?

Tags: react-native, dictionary, mapbox, draw, react-native-mapbox-gl

I want to add react native mapbox a draw features. Like here

```
https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-tu-pwly8?file=/src/index.js:0-978
```

Is something like this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

MapBox has it's React Native SDK (react-native-mapbox-gl). they're actively maintaining the repo with bugFixes and feature implementations.

**Current Version:** React Native MapBox GL Release 6.1.1.

**Expo Support:** Feature request open with Expo if you want to see it get in show your support https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/add-mapbox-gl-support

**Deprecation Notice:** (Just moved to active community driven repository)

> This repository is no longer actively maintained. Continued
> development of react-native-mapbox-gl may be found in the community
> driven repository at https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps.
> This new repository uses the latest versions of the MapBox SDKs for
> iOS and Android, and contains a long range of improvements over the
> current one. We recommend you review the change log for the new
> repository and transition to it. This repository will only accept PR's
> containing bug fixes. Any new feature development will happen in the
> new repository.

For more information, check out [Getting Started](https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/blob/master/docs/GettingStarted.md) section

https://github.com/nitaliano/react-native-mapbox-gl/tree/master/example

Comment: I have already added the mapbox to my react-native project. The question I asked is how do I add draw features on the mapbox map in react native, how do I use it? thanks for the answer

Comment: so far i didn't find any drawcontrol related issues or discussion in react-native-mapbox-gl which is in react-mapbox-gl and as they mentioned in official docs - Issues and pull requests should be opened in the project's GitHub repository. - https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/maps-sdk-for-react-native/

Comment: feature request: drawcontrol component like in react-mapbox-gl here - https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/discussions